# Is there an Italian equivalent word for "cool"?

Tags: word-choice, translation

I always had trouble translating "cool" in Italian.

It's tempting to translate the English term "cool" with "figo"; this seems to convey the wide *meaning* of cool well enough (surely better than other common translations like "fantastico" or "forte"), but the *register* is often inappropriate.

"Cool" is less colloquial than "figo", and, most importantly, it doesn't have any vulgar connotation; I can say that something is "figo" when talking with a friend, but I would never say it to my boss or write it in an advertisement (while I've seen "cool" used in almost any non-extremely-formal context).

So: is there some way to convey both the wide meaning *and* the register of "cool" in Italian?

Comment: In Tuscany we say "ganzo" and its meaning is really near to "cool", but it's a regional word. It's understood by all Italians, but it's normally used only in Tuscany, I think. "ganzo" sometimes (and still in Tuscany, I believe) is used also to identify an extramarital lover. For example, you can say "Luisa ha il ganzo", "Lorenzo ha la ganza", though I don't hear it very often, it's mostly used by old people and it depends on a location.

Comment: I heard "ganzo" used often in translations, since it has the same semantic and a similar register of "cool" (IIRC in Italian translations of Calvin & Hobbes it's used very often), but, at least to me (I'm from Milan) it sounds a bit "forced" (I don't know why, but it feels a bit like adult people who try to imitate teen slang).

Comment: (OTOH, I agree that it's often a "safe" translation with generally no negative/vulgar perceived connotation, so +1 :) )

Comment: As i said, only in Tuscany is used normally, it sounds more normal than "forte!" or "grande!", as in the northern italy, but only in a colloquial conversation is normal to say "figa" with the meaning of "accidenti!" and here "figa" sounds very strange.

Comment: thx for grammar editing.. i'm not so pro in written english..

Comment: I find the alternatives (even the ones proposed in the accepted answer) almost terrible: if forced to translate "cool" in an advertisement, for example, either I'd try to find some workaround, or I'd go for "cool", untranslated. See: http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=cool

Comment: In provincia di Perugia si usa la parola "bulo".

Comment: A livello nazionale mi accodo alla ottima risposta di Gabriele Petronella. Aggiungo, a Taranto si usano i termini "a uerre" e "a uerre probbie", tradotto in italiano: <code>a uerre = la guerra
a uerre probbie = proprio la guerra (viene usato il termine proprio come pleonastico)
</code>

Comment: To the answerers giving replies about local terms used in specific towns: while they are interesting in and of themselves, they are OT in a site about Italian language, and specifically in response to a question asking how to express a particular concept in Italian. At most, they are comments.

Comment: In the dialect from Naples you can say *frisco* which litterally translates *cool*. IE *omm' frisco* is a good translation for *cool man*. Anyway nobody outside the southern Italy will understand this translation.

Comment: Some relevant remarks about the possible Italian words for “cool”: http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2015/09/21/traduzione-cool/

Comment: What about "pazzesco"? Is that not used for "cool"?

Comment: @user2338: "pazzesco" is more like "incredible"; also, you don't usually say "pazzesco" of a person.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no way of conveying both meaning and register.

Here's a few options, each one of them has issues

- ***figo***, vulgar connotation, possibly NSFW
- ***fico***, slightly less vulgar than *figo*, but probably not enough
- ***bello***, appropriate in some contexts, but it generally loses the meaning
- ***forte***, only works in some sentences (*Forte quel tipo!*, *Forte!*), but it can have other meanings
- ***tosto***, again, works only with specific sentences

The only word I know people have being using to translate *cool* almost directly is ***togo***.

I came to know it as an expression used in the popular sitcom *Camera Cafè* by the character [Silvano](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silvano_Rogi), but it apparently has older origins. According to the comments it was used a lot in the 80's, 
but I don't know the etymology of it.

It has basically the same meaning of ***figo***, without the vulgar connotation.
However it sounds a little bit weird/lame, and I wouldn't feel comfortable in using it nowadays. Nonetheless I've heard people saying it in exclamations (and I always look at them suspiciously...)

Comment: my cousins from Cosenza were using **togo** a lot 10-20 years ago, I think it's still used

Comment: thanks for the input, I wasn't aware of it. Do you know something else about the regional diffusion of such word?

Comment: *togo* was widely used in the 80's in Lombardy. I would also add "figata" as a lighter version of "figo"

Comment: @Sklivvz thanks, I added a note about the use of *togo*, since apparently you and mucio agree on it being used in the 80s. However I'm not sure that *figata* is lighter than *figo*.

Comment: Well done, answer accepted; I thought that this could probably be a very common question, so now we have something to link.

Comment: I'm not sure that the difference between “figo” and “fico” is so much in degree as it is in regional origin, the former being more of a northern form, the latter central-southern, as in “cagare” vs. “cacare”. Cf. http://youtu.be/HJ0Yh5wZjpc

Comment: You may be right, even though I effectively use it in that sense. To my ear *fico* sounds slightly less harsh than *figo*

Comment: I think figata it's just the noun derived from figo, I have also heard ficata, but less often

Comment: Please note that "togo" is (was) prevalently used in the north. Never heard it in southern Italy except form the guy in Camera Cafe ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can use "bello" or "grande" (beside "fantastico" and "forte" that you've mentioned) to translate "cool".

Comment: Their meaning is not the same as "cool". Bello is too generic, it doesn't convey the "coolness". "Forte" would work just as an exclamation ("Cool!" -> "Forte!"). How would you translate all those hideous titles like "the 10 coolest gadgets", "the coolest place to work" & co.?

Comment: in these cases "cool" means something between "molto interessante" and "alla moda/del momento", but also "attraente": I 10 gadget del momento or Il posto di lavoro più attraente. Unfortunately transalation is never 1 to 1

Comment: another way to translate cool can be also "giusto", but it sounds to me quite old fashioned. "The Fonz is cool" can be transalted "Fonzie è uno giusto". So "I 10 gadget più giusti del momento", "Il posto di lavoro più 'giusto'", but in the second case better specify  with quotation marks

Comment: Eh, "giusto" could have been a great candidate... 30 years ago :) +1 anyway, I know there's no universal solution

Answer (score 4):

"Splendido!"  can be used, too.

It refers to something being wonderful. 
It´s origin is the infinitive "splendere" which means "shine".

It is used more by adult people but can be used for every situation where something stands out from the usual.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! This, more than an answer, looks like a comment. Would you please try and expand it?

Comment: you should explain **when** "splendido" may be used.

Answer (score 4):

You could say

> forte
>
> bello
>
> fantastico

or

> buono

Buono is used more for good even though.

Answer (score 3):

"Splendido" is a perfect translation of cool; of course only one of them. In the Free Dictionary Online you will find "excellent" and "first rate" (from the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language 2011) and "sophisticated" and "elegant" (from the Collin's English Dictionary). Sometimes that is exactly what "cool" means.
The use of "splendido" has also another advantage: whoever wants to learn our language does not really need to learn fico, figo and figata, which I simply find ghastly.

I imagine that the downvote does not refer to the first paragraph. So there must be somebody around who actually prefers the definitions: fico, figo and figata. My warmest wishes (real, not joking) for the future.

Just two days ago I recommended to two teachers of our primary and secondary schools, where the use of those words is unfortunately common, to try all they can to explain to their students that ours is a beautiful language which has much better words for the same meaning, so there is no need to use vulgar expressions.

And here's the Italian:

"Splendido" è una perfetta traduzione di "cool"; naturalmente solo una fra le tante. Nel Free Dictionary Online possiamo trovare "excellent" e "first rate" (dall'American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language 2011) e "sophisticated" ed "elegant" (dal Collin's English Dictionary). A volte quello è esattamente ciò che si intende per 
"cool".
L'uso di "splendido" ha anche un altro vantaggio: chiunque voglia imparare la nostra lingua non ha davvero bisogno di imparare fico, figo and figata, che trovo semplicemente terribili.

Immagino che il voto negativo non si riferisca al primo partagrafo. Quindi ci deve essere qualcuno che preferisce davvero le definizioni: fico, figo and figata. I miei più sentiti auguri (sinceri, non scherzo), per il futuro.

Proprio due giorni fa ho raccomandato a due insegnanti delle nostre scuole elementari e medie, dove l'uso di quelle parole è sfortunatamente comune, di cercare di fare tutto quello che possono per spiegare ai loro studenti che la nostra è una bella lingua che ha parole molto migliori con lo stesso significato, quindi non c'è bisogno di usare espressioni volgari.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases *brillante* could work. Its meaning is "bright", or "shining", and it is also used to name a jewel.

It does not have any colloquial or formal connotation, it does not imply some sentiment (contrary to *fantastico*, for example) and there are also common phrases such as:

- *una persona brillante*
- *una brillante soluzione*

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, it's a bit dated but I would have said that 'mica male' is the equivalent of 'cool'. But then? Doesn't 'cool' go back, at least, to the 1950's?  I guess one could translate it as "not bad". But I think it could also be 'cool'...

From [De Mauro dictionary](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/mica-male):

> formula usata per esprimere apprezzamento, approvazione: mica male quella ragazza!, mica male come idea!.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @lerici! Per favore, cita le fonti come ho fatto io in questo tuo post.

Comment: L'Uinversita' per Stranieri, sedia di Perugia.