# How to translate cool, nice, great in Italian

Tags: translation, phrase-request, english-comparison

I mean “cool”, “nice”, “great” specifically in the generic sense of, if someone is talking to you and they say they did something nice and cool but not amazing or spectacular, you know, something ordinary but cool, like "I just went fishing this weekend", what is a generic way to say "oh, that's nice" or "oh, that's cool". Not cool in the sense of suave, sexy, popular or anything like that. Just a generic and polite way to reply to something someone said they did or something they saw or ate, etc., or that they are going to do. Like, "very nice" for instance.

Comment: I would think "che bello!" or "buono" but I am not sure (che bello! being a little more excited)

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! This is a related question, possibly a duplicate: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/is-there-an-italian-equivalent-word-for-cool

Comment: @Charo I personally don't think it is a duplicate: John is asking about the usage of "cool" as an interjection in a conversation, not as an adjective.

Answer (score 4):

It's not so easy to give a common answer, you can use one of the following:

- Bello (neutral)
- Forte (a little childish)
- Interessante (formal)

but I usually skip directly to a follow up question, like

> Com'è andata?

Or

> Ti è piaciuto?

To better continue the conversation.

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!!!

Comment: thanks, i think that makes sense. what about "bene!" or "buono!" for this use?

Comment: They have a slight different meaning, and should be used if the topic is something that could have gone wrong, like _Ho capito come risolvere il mio problema_, _Ah, bene!_